# pathnames in Common Lisp, filenames with wildcards in them

Tags: common-lisp, filenames, wildcard, clisp, pathname

The characters `*` and `?` are used as wildcards in pathnames. How does one refer to a filename that has `?` as one of its actual characters? For example:

`[18]> (wild-pathname-p #p"foo")
NIL
[19]> (wild-pathname-p #p"foo?")
T`

So referring to the filename "foo?" cannot be done this way. I tried to escape the `?` with a backslash, but that didn't work. I tried going unicode by using `\u3f` or `\u003f`, but that didn't work.

How do I refer to a file that contains a wildcard as part of its name: How to probe it, open it, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the implementation, but for some, a backslash does in fact work. But because namestrings are strings, to get a string with a backslash in it, you have to escape the backslash with another backslash. So, for example, `"foo?"` is escaped as `"foo\\?"`, not `"foo\?"`.

Last time I checked, in CLISP, there is no way to refer to files with wildcards in the names. My solution to that is to avoid CLISP.

Comment: SBCL exhibits similar behaviour as CLISP, so apparently the common lisp standard doesn't include a mechanism for escaping the wildcard, which is weird.

What is no less weird is that cltl2, page 628 gives a BNF for pathname namestrings, and this does not include the `?` character. Only `*` ad `**`

Comment: SBCL supports escaping with backslashes.

Comment: Unix-style globbing with `*` and `?` within pathname components is a non-standard but frequent extension to pathnames and namestring syntax.

Comment: Do you mean something like:

`* (wild-pathname-p #p"foo?")

T
* (wild-pathname-p #p"foo\?")

T
* (wild-pathname-p #p"foo\\?")

NIL`

Comment: You can refer to a file with a Unix pathname of "foo?" with #p"foo\\?" in SBCL.

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac running Mac OS X 10.10.3: Clozure CL, SBCL and LispWorks write a pathname with `*` like this:

```
#P"/private/tmp/test.\\*"
```

They might differ in some other details, though.

Comment: (wild-pathname-p #p"test.\\*") returns T in sbcl but NIL in clisp. This seems to be the issue: There is no way of removing the special status of the wildcards in clisp.

Answer (score 0):

SBCL supports `(make-pathname :directory "" :name file)` to escape a `string` to a proper `pathname`.